# Hide gnome launch bar following a launcher click

Tags: gnome, compiz, launcher

I looked on the site, but found no match. I looked through ***compiz Settings Manager*** but didn't see anything that would 
help me.

Using 14.04 LTS with gnome installed. I can't remember where of if there's a location to set the behavior for the launch bar so that following the click of a launcher from the bar, the launcher bar will disappear.

Currently, if I click and leave the mouse atop the launcher I clicked, the launch bar remains visible. I'd like to have it slide away following a launcher icon click.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about [Unity](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Ubuntu_13.04_Desktop.png/800px-Ubuntu_13.04_Desktop.png), not [Gnome](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/GNOME_Shell.png)?

Comment: I'm confused. I did the stock, 14.04 LTS 64-bit install, and installed Gnome on top of that (at least I thought I did) because I thought Gnome more closely matched my 12.04 LTS interface, and I can't say for sure but I think I now have a mix of both running. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

**You can set it to auto-hide**

Go to the system settings, click on appearance, then there is a tab called behaviour, in there you can specify a few things about the launcher.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I do know about that, but the "make the launcher bar disappear after clicking a launcher icon" unf isn't one of them. :-Z

Comment: I think I'd researched something different in the past and had been directed to compiz (?) config settings manager to change whatever that issue was at the time. I'm wondering if something similar holds the key this time--something that has a true/false toggle that holds or dismisses the laucher bar following a launcher icon click.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is, at least that I know of, and I have CompizConfig, tweak tool, Ubuntu tweak, unity tweak, etc.

Comment: Possibly. I'm sorry I can't help further. :-(